# SQL Server Reporting Service - Reference another dataset?

Tags: reporting-services

I have two datasets in a SQL Server 2008 reporting services report. I need to attach a WHERE clause to the second one that will contain a value from the first one. How should I write that second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, you should run a SUB query within the where clause.

SELECT title FROM books
WHERE author_id IN (SELECT id FROM authors);

Comment: If the subquery `(SELECT id FROM authors)` returns more than one row, the query will raise error. `WHERE author_id IN (SELECT id FROM authors)` could be used instead.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  No need to vote down when the answer was accepted for his question.